# Mount redis server to work with new volume

Tags: linux, redis, servicestack

I have redis server on linux that i use for redis queues i have in my app.

The root drive is getting full (90%) and i am looking for a way to increase the storage or use another drive i have on this server with a lot of space.

Reading some posts in the official redis site did not help me find the thing i was looking for.
I saw there only the instructions of installing new redis server (which is not what i need).

Is there someone who know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I see there dir ./ but i do not have any file related to redis there.
I know that the redis file is on other path and actually saw it.
The problem is that i do not see this path mentioned in the redis.conf i found.